# Can I change only address name?

Tags: javascript, iframe, location

I want to change address but don't change page, only **`iframe`**. Like:

```
<iframe id='biframe' ></iframe>
<script>
    window.biframe.src = 'page/' + window.location.pathname;
</script>
```

If users go to page like **`localhost/books`** (server don't have this folder) and request go to page **`localhost/page/books`**, but user don't see it and take infromation from **iframe**

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem, please tell us about X -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: forget: if user go from link like /music, it's action send this link to iframe and addres page just changed, don't reload page